# Panel that expands when new components are added

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to have multiple vertical panels in my frame which will start with a button in them. When I push these buttons they will add more buttons to these panels. When new buttons are added, the panels should expand and push all the other panels below them. I added an example image of what I want above.

I am not new with layout managers, are there any layout manager that I can use for this? If not what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` with columns set to 1 and rows set to 0.

Comment: The first thing you should do: visit the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Basically your question is too broad, as ther are multiple ways to address this, and it really depends on your current knowledge to understand what works best for you. Having said that, you should look into a JScrollPane for example. So, your Panel 1 should got into such a scroll pane, and that one would add scroll bars if the "inside" component requires more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the layout manager of the child panel and the layout manager of the parent panel. Both layout manager need to be able to grow. Based on the picture you could use a vertical `BoxLayout` for both parent and child panels.

When you add a component to a visible panel you then need to `revalidate()` the panel to invoke the layout manager so the basic code would be:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
panel.add( button );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, BoxLayout did exactly what I want. Now i am trying to set the width of buttons to the width of the panel they belong. Do you have a suggestion about that?

Comment: Well, a BoxLayout respects the "maximum size" of the each component. For a JButton the maximum size is equal to the preferred size. You should be able to use a GridLayout. The components is a GridLayout will change size to fill the space available. Or you could use a GridBagLayout. Read the tutorial and play with each layout manager to learn its features.